# How can I vertically center a div of unknown height inside a div of known height?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically center `<div id="innner">` inside `<div id="outer">`, when the contents of `<div id="innner">` are dynamically generated, and thus variable in height. That is,

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        // dynamically generated stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#outer{
    float:left; 
    height:50%; 
    margin-bottom:-120px;
}

#inner{
    clear:both; 
    height:240px; 
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
Content here
</div>
</div>
```